# Calling a JavaScript function defined in .fxml file from the JavaFX Controller

Tags: javascript, java, javafx, fxml

I have a JavaScript function defined in my .fxml file called ExecuteFunction(). Is there anyway I could call my JavaScript function defined in the .fxml file from my JavaFX Controller?
I tried using ScriptEngine but couldn't find a suitable approach.

View.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <?language javascript?>

  <fx:script>
      function ExecuteFunction(){
          print("function invoked");
      }
  </fx:script>
```

Controller.java

```
public void invokeJavascript(){

    // I want to call the ExecuteFunction() method in View.fxml   

}
```

Comment: Put your code here, so people see your effort and clear their understanding

Comment: I'm just wondering why you would want to do this. If you have a controller file, doesn't it make more sense to define the handlers there, instead of in javascript in the FXML file?

Comment: I have moved some of the logic to my javascript function, I use it for some validation. The requirement is, I have a common controller which should be used to call a given javascript function defined in every .fxml file.

Comment: @MahdiAlkhatib I've added a sample code of what i wish to achieve.